# How to find an empty vector in a list?

Tags: r, string

I have a list where each element is a string. It happens that some of the elements are an empty character vector.

I want to get the indices of all those empty elements, but haven't found a syntax which delivers them.

```
my.list <- lapply(c("I", "am", "not", "empty"), function(x) x)
my.list[[5]] <- character(0)
my.list[[6]] <- character(0)
```

All things I've tried (such as `my.list==""`, `my.list==character(0)`) deliver something entirely different. If I unlist the list, it suddenly misses the empty elements and is only 4 elements long.

What is the correct syntax to find the empty character vectors?

Comment: try `lengths(my.list)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `R` `3.2` version, from which `lengths` function is available:

```
which(!lengths(my.list))
[1] 5 6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
which(sapply(my.list,length)==0)
```

Comment: `sapply(my.list, length)` can now be replaced  with  `lengths(my.list)` in newer R versions

Answer (score 1):

You could use `length`:

`lapply(my.list, length) == 0`

For character vectors specifically,

```
f <- function(v){

  is.character(v) && length(v) == 0

}

vapply(my.list, f, logical(1))
```

Mind you, Richard Telford's comment is the best answer to your question.